# Masm code translated into Nasm code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, masm

How can I translate the code from masm into nasm code.

```
foo_get_counter       proc      object:DWORD  

                      mov       ebx, object  

                      mov       eax, foo.m_counter[ebx]  

                      ret  

foo_get_counter       endp
```

the part I do not understand is proc object:DWORD

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, it's a parameter passed to the function. You could find a macro set for Nasm that includes a `proc` macro. I think in "raw Nasm" syntax, something like...

```
; does "proc" imply "global foo_get_counter"? Might.
foo_get_counter:        

                  push ebp
                  mov ebp, esp

; could %define object ebp + 8 

                  mov       ebx, [ebp + 8]  

                  mov       eax, [foo.m_counter + ebx]  
                  leave
                  ret
```

I don't know what `foo.m_counter` is. You might need a change of syntax there. Possibly `[foo + foo.m_counter + ebx]` or similar. Depending on Masm's `.model` directive, the `ret` might need to be `ret 4` (if it's `STDCALL` ?). Good luck.